# How can I write a regex that finds everything but 4 digit numbers like 2000 or 1990 or 1234?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this:

```
Film_relase_date:1970_films_by_20th_Century_Fox
```

I would like to create a regex that matches all text except 1970, resulting in:

```
Film_relase_date:_films_by_20th_Century_Fox
```

I tried with the regex:

```
[^\d{4}]
```

But this regex returns:

```
Film_relase_date:_films_by_th_Century_Fox
```

And therefore also excludes the 20 which instead I would like to be matched.
How can I improve the regex?

EDIT:
I want to use this regex to do something like:

```
x = 'Film_relase_date: 1970_films_by_20th_Century_Fox'

REPLACE (x, "Anything that is not a 4-digit number", "Non-Space") = 1970
```

Comment: You could match `(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/PWE1Kk/1

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes this works, but how do I negate the expression? I would need the regex to exclude the 4-digit number from the text. I am using this regex in a REPLACE function where I want to replace anything that is not a 4-digit number with a non-space

Comment: Looking at the desired result `re.sub(r"(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)", "", "Film_relase_date:1970_films_by_20th_Century_Fox")` see https://ideone.com/CrNcIo

Comment: Would your text always follow that same pattern where you wish to remove the 4 characters following the colon?

Comment: Yes exactly, the number that interests me is always in that format. I didn't explain myself very well, I mean the regex must be something like:
                                                                                                                         
 REPLACE ("anything that is not a 4-digit number", "Non-Space") = 4-digit number.                      
                                                                                                                              
 Sorry it's my fault I wasn't clear enough, thanks everyone for the advice so far!

Comment: That makes me wonder if you can use: `print(x[:x.find(':')+1] + x[x.find(':')+5:])` where `x = 'Film_relase_date:1970_films_by_20th_Century_Fox'`.

Comment: I don't think I can do it, the regex must be used in the SPARQL REPLACE function, it is part of a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `{4}` is supposed to be added `after` the character class, not inside.

Anyway, if you want to match "all text except 1970", you can use the following regex:

```
([^\d]|(?<!\d)\d(?!\d{3}(?!\d))\d*)?
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV03iw/3).

This regex matches:

- a non-digit character **or**
- a digit char that is nor preceded by another digit and it is not followeb by exactly 3 digits

Comment: That would not work https://regex101.com/r/taKWuj/1

Comment: You're right, because \b does not divide \d from underscore.

Comment: This seems to be the right solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all except 4 digits, I would suggest an unrolled version matching either 1-3 or 5 digits asserting not followed by a digit to prevent consecutive matching digits.

If you don't want to cross newlines, you could use `[^\d\r\n]` instead of `\D`

```
\D+(?:(?:\d{1,3}|\d{5,})(?!\d)\D*)*
```

*Explanation*

- `\D+` Match 1+ non digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\d{1,3}|\d{5,})` Match either 1-3 or 5 or more digits
- `(?!\d)\D*` Negative lookahead, assert not a digit directly to the right followed by matching optional non digits
- `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpBzJ3/1)

**Note** that if you want to match 4 digits only, you could perhaps extract the 4 digits using `(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)` instead of replacing with an empty string.

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KwXfvp/1)